# pandas/sqlalchemy/pyodbc: Result object does not return rows from stored proc when UPDATE statement appears before SELECT

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm using SQL Server 2014, pandas 0.23.4, sqlalchemy 1.2.11, pyodbc 4.0.24, and Python 3.7.0. I have a very simple stored procedure that performs an UPDATE on a table and then a SELECT on it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_1
    @v2     INT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE my_table_1 
    SET v2 = @v2 
    ;

    SELECT * from my_table_1
    ;
END 
GO
```

This runs fine in MS SQL Server Management Studio. However, when I try to invoke it via Python using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc://@MODEL_TESTING'
    engine = create_engine(conn_str)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("EXEC my_proc_1 33", conn)
        print(df)
```

I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return
>   rows. It has been closed automatically.

(Please let me know if you want full stack trace, I will update if so)

When I remove the UPDATE from the stored proc, the code runs and the results are returned. Note also that selecting from a table other than the one being updated does not make a difference, I get the same error. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Add a `SET NOCOUNT ON;` statement at the beginning of your stored procedure and see if that helps.

Comment: That worked in my test example! Am testing now with the real code. Please feel free to post this as an answer - if it work with the real code I will gladly accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the UPDATE statement is returning a row count, which is a scalar value, and the rows returned by the SELECT statement are "stuck" behind the row count where pyodbc cannot "see" them (without additional machinations).

It is considered a best practice to ensure that our stored procedures always start with a `SET NOCOUNT ON;` statement to suppress the returning of row count values from DML statements (UPDATE, DELETE, etc.) and allow the stored procedure to just return the rows from the SELECT statement.

Comment: In addition to the NOCOUNT ON; I had to add SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF, as well as my stored procedure produced warnings: "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation".

Answer (score 0):

For me I got the same issue for another reason, I was using `sqlachmey` the newest syntax `select` to get the entries of a table and I had forgot to write the name of the table class I want to get values from, so I got this error, so I had only added the name of the table as an argument to fix the error.

the code leaded to the error

```py
query = select().where(Assessment.created_by == assessment.created_by)
```

simply fix it by adding the table class name sometimes issues are only in the syntax hhh

```py
query = select(Assessment).where(Assessment.created_by == assessment.created_by)
```